# pass the value of a variable to another method C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am new to programming. How do I pass the value of a variable to another method? The code variable gets a value, but when the method exits, it is reset to zero. I need to set the visitcode variable to the value of the code variable. I've tried declaring a code variable in the public class, but it doesn't work either. i did it like this

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
Int32 code = new Int32();



protected void Repeater1_OnItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "visitcode")
    {
        Int32 code = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    }
}

protected void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string num = number.Value;
    string document = doc.Value;
    string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff";
    string stringDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(format);
    string visitcode = code
}
```

Comment: You need to create a global variable that can be accessible at class/namespace/all level. Please have a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow what you want, but, why not create a private variable which stores the value, and later, any other method can read it?

Comment: First thing to clarify. Is this an ASP.NET classic app or ASP.NET Core one?

Comment: just declare `private int code;` in this class. Then write `code = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);`. But remember that in web applications, variable values will not persist across requests (unless they're form fields in viewstate, or session variables), so you may find that in the button click is still not populated.

Comment: @Steve I think the use of Repeater marks it out fairly clearly as WebForms (and therefore must be .NET Framework, not Core)

Comment: Please *[edit]* your question if you want to show more code.

Comment: Then probably is better to point the OP to some kind ot tutorial on ASP.NET State. For some examples see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_managing_state.htm

Comment: @zaknafein By the way, if you're new to programming, I would not recommend you to learn WebForms, as you seem to be doing. It's a legacy technology from 20 years ago, and is not even available in the new .NET 5. Instead, learn a newer web framework like Razor Pages, Blazor or even MVC, one which has a future and also can take advantage of newer technology and improvements in .NET and the web in general. (And if you are completely new to programming, please start with simple C# console applications before you add in the complexity of a web-based environment.)

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/ has more info on the latest .NET stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the update...one problem with this is that in `Int32 code = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);` you are trying to declare a new variable `code` when you already have another one declared in the class. Just remove the `Int32` from the beginning of the line. But still, bear in mind my remarks about variables being persistent between requests, it may still not work. Try the tutorial that Steve posted. .... But really, if you have any choice in the matter, please abandon this project completely and learn a newer technology.

Comment: @ADyson the problem has not disappeared, the code variable becomes 0 after the Repeater1_OnItemCommand method completes.

Comment: One more time, read the comments about variables persisting between requests. I'd guess it's likely that the button click happens only with a new request to the server?

Comment: @ADyson yes, there is a new request for this button. there is a second button that should write this data to the sql database

Comment: Ok well, again, read the tutorial that Steve provided about how to maintain state in between requests in WebForms applications.

Comment: (But seriously, again one more time, unless someone is forcing you to learn WebForms, then it's not a good thing to learn for a new programmer. Try something else.)

Comment: @ADyson i understand ... but i need to make one page with two buttons. and I started doing this way. learning new things for the sake of this small task is not an opportunity.

Comment: Maybe we weren't clear. You can't do what you have asked without _learning new things_ A variable declared inside a method block is local to that block and cannot be used outside of that block, unless..... go back to my second comment and the many others from @ADyson...

Comment: @Steve Yes, I need to use the data that the variable receives in this method. maybe it is possible to call this method in another method? I don't know what to do anymore ...

Comment: Use a session variable. Did you read the tutorial?

Comment: @ADyson Yes. I try to write the code according to this tutorial

Comment: Show us exactly what you did then, if it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each HTTP request is treated as a new request, this means that your "code" variable is always cleaned every time it reaches the server, so ASP.NET WebForms offers a way to store temporary values in the session variable.

Your code could see like this:

```
protected void Repeater1_OnItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "visitcode")
    {
        Session["Code"] = e.CommandArgument;
    }
}
```

In a second request, you could retrieve the value as follows:

```
protected void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    string visitcode = Session["Code"];
}
```

As I mentioned, Session variable is temporary so you have to validate if your value is different to NULL, if so this means that the session is over.

I hope it is useful for you

Comment: Thank you. it works! but every time the page is refreshed, it creates a record in the database. I tried to close the session Session.Clear (), then the application crashes with an error. I need the session to be reset when the page is refreshed. but when the button is clicked, the value is updated and works as I need

Comment: if i clear the variable then error when refreshing the page: An object reference does not point to an instance of an object.

Comment: WebForms naturally works with server controls. Every interaction with button, checkbox, to name a few is raised a request to the server so there is a flag (IsPostBack) to know if the page is loaded for the first time or users are using it. You must validate in Page_Load method like so: if(!IsPostBack){ //Code executed when the page is load for the first time }